# Что значит язык "Base" в списке языков локализации?

Tags: локализация, xcode

Я добавил в настройках проекта кроме английского в список языков еще русский. Но теперь откуда-то появился также язык "Base" у некоторых файлов в списке их языковых версий. Что это за зверь, для чего нужен, и как его использовать?

Comment: Также заметил, что там где находится список языков проекта, есть галочка Use Base Internationalization. Видимо, она имеет отношение к этому.

Comment: В конечном итоге написал небольшую статью по локализации, там в том числе про базовый язык и про тестирование разных языков. Надеюсь, кому-то поможет: http://g-rain-design.ru/blog/posts/xcode-localization/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base это основной "язык" приложения, так сказать нишевой, основной. Раньше по-умолчанию это был English, теперь Base. Вы сами вправе выбирать каким он будет. Но рекомендация, оставить его английским.

Comment: Т.е. в него надо просто скопировать английские языковые фразы? А если снять галочку Use Base Internationalization, что тогда будет?
Т.е. у меня сейчас получается 3 языка - Base, English, Russian. Или English надо удалить?

Comment: Копировать ничего не надо, надо в свойствах языковых файлах в самом xCode указать "Localization" - он см все сделает. Снимать галку не рекомендуется, вы фактически языковое ядро "выключите". Как хотите, если у вас Base=English - удаляйте. 
Base - это язык (лингвистический) разработчика. Это основа языка.
Просто раньше Apple считал Base и English равными. Теперь вы в качестве Base можете выбирать любой. То есть изначально делать свое приложение на русском языке и локализовывать на английский.